# "String or binary data would be truncated" Error in Delete Command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am getting this error while trying to execute a delete command in a stored procedure:

> String or binary data would be truncated

Is it possible to get such error in delete command? If yes then what are the possible causes?

Comment: Post the source code query if possible that would help us to answer it.

Comment: Are you using any triggers ?

Comment: Thanks Vishwanath. My delete query is very simple. Its  DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @Id

Comment: @KuldipMCA: No I am not using any trigger. Its simple a procedure having delete command. If I comment that delete query then it execute without this error.

Comment: Check if there's a ON DELETE Trigger for that MyTable.

Comment: @Ernest He has mention earlier he doesn't have any triggers on it.

Comment: @John Please, show us results of this query `select * from sys.triggers where parent_id=object_id(N'YOUR_TABLE NAME')`

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi - It's not because he mentioned it, it's true. If I could get a penny for every time I was certain about something only to find later I didn't know the whole picture... Until OP posts what has been asked, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Hi @Igor. There is 0 record when I execute this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally happens when you try to insert data.

The data you inserting might have been with the more data size, than it is actually declared in database. Thats why this error is comming.

Do check with datasize in database and actual datasize you are trying to insert int database.

Comment: question asked in aspect of delete not Insert.

Comment: @VishwanathDalvi he is just asking about possibility of delete. But i know its about insert. Until he doesnt posts his code/query, exact answer can not be given.

Comment: Thanks @Freelancer: Its simple a procedure having delete command. If I comment that delete query then it execute without this error.

Comment: @John Also Table structure

Comment: Sry abt this @VishwanathDalvi. Its having approx 2000 lines. But I get rid of this error whenever I comment this sql statement: DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = Id

Comment: +1 *when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth*

Comment: @Freelancer - I'm convinced this is the right answer and won't change my mind until proven otherwise :). OP should turn on tracing and check what get's executed.